# Import a module with optional arguments python

Tags: python, python-import

Currently, I have a file called utils.py where I keep all my functions and another file called main.py.

In my utils file, I have a two functions that load and save to a json file, along with a bunch of other functions that will edit the data.

```
def save_league(league_name, records):
    with open('%s.json' % league_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(records))

def load_league(league_name):
    with open('%s.json' % league_name, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        records = json.loads(content)
        return records
```

I am trying to add optional arguments for the save_league function by changing the function to:

```
def save_league(name = league_name, r = records):
    with open('%s.json' % name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(r))
```

This way the file will save just from save_league().

However, when I try to import a function with optional arguments in main.py, I get a name error because the default arguments are not set at the beginning.

```
NameError: name 'league_name' is not defined
```

Is it possible import functions with optional args into another file or do I have to combine the two files into one?

Comment: You have to give a default *value* to your keyword argument. `league_name` is in fact not defined in this context. However, looking at your `save_league` method, I don't see why you are trying to provide default arguments. You should probably keep them as positional arguments to ensure that the needed arguments are provided.

Comment: What do you expect `league_name` to be?  What do you want the default value to be?

Comment: My thinking behind using default args is that because I input league_name when i run load_league, by returning league_name, I could set the default arg for my save_league function to what I inputted in the load_league function.

Comment: @Tofuistofu: That's not really what default arguments are for.   Default arguments are usually stateless, meaning they don't depend on previous calls.

Comment: So I am trying to make the default name value of the save_league function to be what I input when I load the file.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do using a method other than default args?

Comment: @Tofuistofu: You should not try to do what you are trying to do.  It's not a good design.  Being explicit is a good thing.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the feedback. I'll just keep it as is if it's better practice to do so.